# How to build multiple webpack projects in a single command

Tags: javascript, webpack

There are two folders in my project, each has a `webpack.config.js` file.

```
Ckeditor
Wiris
```

I would like to run the build command for the two projects using a single command in the parent dir, and the build output be like,

```
dist/
 Ckeditor -> index.html + bundle + assets
 Wiris -> index.html + bundle + assets
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

When you run webpack, you can specify a config file on the command line with `--config`. You could write a script called `build-all.sh` like this:

```sh
# build-all.sh: runs webpack for all projects

webpack --config Ckeditor/webpack.config.js
webpack --config Wiris/webpack.config.js
```

and then run `bash build-all.sh` to execute.